# Cambiar selector de una ListView java

Tags: javafx

Intentaré ser breve y conciso en mi pregunta-.
Estoy elaborando un reproductor mp3 en Java Fx.

**Mi problema y pregunta es el siguiente:
Cuando selecciono una canción que está en la ListView - viene a ser una Playlist-, se queda sombreada - digamos en azul (Estilo CSS propio )- al presionar el botón avanzar , este selector no cambia a la siguiente canción de la ListView.**

¿ Alguien podría orientarme como solucionar ese problema ?.

> Código que implementa los botones con los métodos de escucha y ListView Lista_Vi, ObservableList.

````
            String mensaje4 = "file:/Volumes/NO NAME/JSP/Reproductor/src/img/adelante.png";
            Image img4 = new Image(mensaje4);
            ImageView view4 = new ImageView(img4);
            view4.setFitHeight(25);
            view4.setPreserveRatio(true);
            siguiente= new Button();
            siguiente.setPrefSize(70, 50);
            siguiente.setGraphic(view4);
            siguiente.setOnAction(e ->{
                uno.stop();
                uno= new Control(canciones_escogidas.escoger());
                uno.play();
                
                listado_canciones.setText(canciones_escogidas.escoge_Nombre().getName());
                **Aquí es donde me gustaría que al ser presionado el botón cambiara la selección de la ListView**
                
            });
            
              //-- BOTÓN PARA RETROCEDER LA CANCIÓN
            String mensaje5 = "file:/Volumes/NO NAME/JSP/Reproductor_etapas/src/img/atrasar.png";
            Image img5 = new Image(mensaje5);
            ImageView view5 = new ImageView(img5);
            view5.setFitHeight(25);
            view5.setPreserveRatio(true);
            atras= new Button();
            atras.setPrefSize(70, 50);
            atras.setGraphic(view5);
            atras.setOnAction(e ->{
                uno.stop();
                uno= new Control(canciones_escogidas.escoger_atras());
                uno.play();
                listado_canciones.setText(canciones_escogidas.escoge_Nombre_atras().getName());
                
                
                
            });```


``` // LIST_VIEW Y OBSERVABLELIST
            //LISTADO DE CANCIONES PARA ESCOGER
            listado_canciones = new Label("CANCIONES");
            listado_canciones.getStyleClass().add("Label");

            Lista_Vi = new ListView<File>();
            Lista_Vi.getStyleClass().add("Lista");
            /*
             * En el siguiente bucle implementamos a la List View todas las canciones
             * del ArrayList inicializado en la clase Modelo.
             * 
             * Nota: En la variables almacenamos los nombres de las canciones - sin la dirección absoluta -.
             * Estás serán las que verán los usuarios en sus dispositivos. Posteriormente tendremos que concatenar la ruta completa.
             */
            for (File t : canciones_escogidas.getArray_Nombre_Musica()) {
                String prueba = t.getName();
                prueba2 = new File(prueba);
                Lista_Vi.getItems().add(prueba2);
            }
            
            // Se permite seleccionar sola una canción a la vez con la siguiente instrucción
            Lista_Vi.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
            
            // Tamaño de la lista en la app
            Lista_Vi.setPrefHeight(100);
            Lista_Vi.setPrefWidth(20);
            Lista_Vi.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                    nombre_cancion_escogida = "" ;
                    nombre_borrar_cancion ="";
                    list_Obser = Lista_Vi.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
                    String dire = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/";
                    for (File i : list_Obser) {
                        try {
                               // --- Se recorre la ObservableList donde está añadidas todas las canciones del ListView.
                               //     Al estar en el método de escucha almacena lo seleccionado por el usuario.
                            nombre_cancion_escogida += i ;
                            
                            nombre_borrar_cancion += i;
                            listado_canciones.setText(i.getName().toString());
                            
                               // --- Concatenamos la ruta completa para inicializar el objeto Control que es donde está los métodos que hacen reproduccir la música.
                            apunte =    new File(dire + "/src/audio/" + nombre_cancion_escogida);
                             //System.out.print(i.getAbsoluteFile());
                            uno = new Control(apunte);
                              // ---  Esta línea de código es fundamental para conocer la posición de la canción. Usada en los métodos de la clase Modelos - que es a la que per
                              //      tenece el objeto canciones_escogidas.
                            
                            canciones_escogidas.posicion(apunte);
                            //canciones_escogidas.siguiente_item(nombre_cancion_escogida);
                            
                        
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            System.out.println("Error en la clase principal - main - en la interación del list_Obser");
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    
                }
                
            });``

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRJTp.png
````

Answer (score 0):

**Con método `selectNext()`**

[image: next iteration javafx]

el comportamiento es : si hay otro ítem después del seleccionado ; selecciona el siguiente y , si es el último ; limpia la selección.

Este es un ejemplo de javafx en una sola clase que puede probar

**App.class**

```
public class App extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    var list = new ListView<String>();
    list.getItems().addAll("Everyday is like sunday.mp3",
            "A little respect.mp3",
            "Also sprach Zarathustra.mp3",
            "Arthur's theme.mp3",
            "Cómo hemos cambiado.mp3",
            "El camino.mp3",
            "There is a light that never goes out.mp3");

    var next = new Button("siguiente");
    var box = new VBox(10, list, next);
    var scene = new Scene(box, 640, 480);
    
    next.setOnAction((t) -> {
        list.getSelectionModel().selectNext();
        
    });
    
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda ....